# How to update only status on a Button click using in SQLite in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, arraylist, android-sqlite

I am developing a SQLite database. I created a table which schema is:  name, image, isselected.
The initial status of a message is 0.
I am updating the status on a Button click by using the `setStatus()` method on the database.
But the status does not change.
I want to click my Button once and set the status to 1 and then click it once again to re-set the status to 0.

The `setStatus()` function is shown below:

```
 public int setStatus(People people) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    people.setStatus(1);
    values.put(STATUS, people.getStatus());

    return sqLiteDatabase.update(TABLE_PEOPLE, values, ID + "=?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(people.getId())});

}
```

My Button click event

```
 btnBuildNow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            peopleListSelected = new ArrayList<>();
            for (People people : peopleList) {
                if (people.getStatus()==1) {
                    db.setStatus(people);
                    peopleListSelected.add(people);
                }
            }
            if (peopleListSelected.size() > 0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(BulidActivity.this, AlertList.class);
                intent.putExtra("arrayList", (Serializable) peopleListSelected);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Have you added a row with  "id=" + ISSELECTED to the TABLE_PEOPLE first?

Comment: Where do you set `ISSELECTED`?

Comment: No I have not add row only change status in button click @Serg

Comment: Static data set ISSELECTED=0 @Fildor

Comment: If you have no row with id=0 in the table, update finds nothing to update. Somewhere in your app/activity you have to create and populate the table. Show this code please.

Comment: I have use DB browser  for SQLite software to add static data and isselected is column in database then put tha all value is 0 then click button to change the status 0 to 1 @Serg

Answer (score 0):

You did not pass the id which row you want to update (or you want to update all rows?), ISSELECTED variable is not declared. I mean this line:

```
sqldb.update(TABLE_PEOPLE, cv, "id=" + ISSELECTED, null);
```

I would write like this (now I can't test it). I would pass the selected id to the update method's third parameter (that is the where clause, see the documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html):

```
public String setStatus(String selected) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqldb = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("isselected", 1);
    sqldb.update(TABLE_PEOPLE, cv, "id=" + selected, null);
    sqldb.close();
    return "Anything you want";
}
```

Another possible solution is to write your query directly:

```
public String setStatus(String selected) {
        SQLiteDatabase sqldb = this.getWritableDatabase();
        sqldb.execSQL("UPDATE TABLE_PEOPLE SET ISSELECTED=1 WHERE id=" + selected);
        sqldb.close();
        return "Anything you want";
    }
```

**EDIT:**
Sorry, I forget to tell to modify the button click event, where `db.setStatus();` is called: use `db.setStatus(people.getId());`, or something like this (people.id, or something which represents the id of the people object, if it have any. If it don't have id, somehow you should acquire the id from the database.)

Comment: Okay i will try it!

Comment: But how to set and get this status in object model?